# Logout clicked in php but page doesn't remove logged in html details until refresh

Tags: php, html

When I signed in and click on logout button, it successfully logs me out and returns back to normal, i.e. with login form presented. Perfect!

However, if I sign in and go to another page (which contains session_start();) and then click on a link to return me back to the login page, and then click on the logout button, but this time it even though it logs me out, but username and logout button still stays on the page until I hit refresh.

Logout:

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location: login.php');
exit();
?>
```

Login page:

```
<?php session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['email'])) ?>
...html form...
}else { echo '<a href ="logout.php">logout</a>';
}
```

I'm not too sure where the problem lies since logout works perfectly when I'm on the same page, but when I return it partially works.

**EDIT:** I even tried adding header("Refresh:0; url=login.php"); in logout but somehow it doesn't work. I need to manually click on refresh button to change back the webpage to logged out view.

Comment: I was typing half way but decided to paste my code instead so hence typo :S but I've fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a caching problem.  Even after the redirect to index.php, if index.php was cached by the browser, it will display the same info.  So in your index.php put:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate',true);
```

To make the browser not cache it.

Comment: I put this after session start and tested it out but still getting the same problem. It's strange, if I log in and logout in index page is fine. If I log in and go to another page and hit the logout button on the other page, again, it's fine. But when I login on index page, go to another page, then go back to index page and then hit logout, ---it logs out --- but doesn't revert back to non-logged in state.

Comment: Certain versions of IE may require more headers to make it stop caching. `"Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"` and maybe also `"Pragma: no-cache"`.

Answer (score 0):

The php manual recommends this process:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
header( "location: index.php");
```

Comment: A link for this would be beneficial. *"The proof's in the pudding"* ;-)

Comment: Doesn't work. Maybe I can add in refresh page after logout button is clicked?